# Simple Off Canvas Menu Not Functioning

Tags: html, css, yui

I've created a simple main navigation, however it's not working when you click the menu button.  the code looks correct but maybe there is a disconnect I'm not seeing.  Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

The site I am working on is: offcanvas.squarespace.com

HTML

```
<a href="#main-navigation" class="menu-link">MENU</a>
```

CSS

```
    #main-navigation.active {
        -webkit-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        -moz-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        -o-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        -ms-transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
        transform: translate(-13.755em, 0px);
}

.menu-link {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      left:10em;
      color:black;
      font-size: 24px;
}
```

YUI

```
  Y.one('.menu-link').on('click', function(){
  Y.one('#main-navigation').toggleClass('active');
  Y.one('.container').toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: I can tell you that the issue is your active class isnt being applied to the element.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make the active class applied to the element?

Comment: I don't have any experience with YUI, I can tell you how with jQuery though.

Comment: How would you do it with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This is the jQuery I use with an off-canvas navigation that I developed for myself.

With my implementation...  I apply a class to the body tag.  From there all my CSS that makes the navigation expand starts with body.off-canvas.  This way I don't need to toggle multiple classes on different elements etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#open-nav').click(function() {
        $('#body').toggleClass('off-canvas');
    });
});
```